# How to compare the difference between a new branch and the master branch in git?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a new branch named `test_branch` containing more than one commit and I want to merge it to the `master` branch. Before merging I need to get the difference between `test_branch` and `master` branch with GitLab CI.

I tried to use the command below but it failed:

```
# the variable $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE is "Merge branch 'test_branch' into 'master'" so I can get the new branch name
git diff $(echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE | awk -F "'" '{print $2}') master --name-status
```

and shows:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'test_branch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Why is it failed and what is the correct way doing this?

Comment: Is it the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same situation where commands such as git diff origin or git diff origin master produced the error reported in the question, namely Fatal: ambiguous argument...

To resolve the situation, I ran the command

```
git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/master
```

to set refs/remotes/origin/HEAD to point to the origin/master branch.

Before running this command, the output of git branch -a was:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

After running the command, the error no longer happened and the output of git branch -a was:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

(Other answers have already identified that the source of the error is HEAD not being set for origin. But I thought it helpful to provide a command which may be used to fix the error in question, although it may be obvious to some users.)

Additional information:

For anybody inclined to experiment and go back and forth between setting and unsetting refs/remotes/origin/HEAD, here are some examples.

To unset:

```
git remote set-head origin --delete
```

To set:
(additional ways, besides the way shown at the start of this answer)
git remote set-head origin master to set origin/head explicitly
OR

```
git remote set-head origin --auto
```

to query the remote and automatically set origin/HEAD to the remote's current branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can :

- use `HEAD`, which is a pointer to the active commit,
- use [other `CI` env variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html), such as `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` or `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`, which will hold the name of the branch that triggered the pipeline -- without needing to `awk` your way out of it.

---

Check if any of the following commands :

```
git diff --name-status origin/master HEAD

git diff --name-status origin/master $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
git diff --name-status origin/master $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

displays the diff you are looking for.

Comment: Note that various CI systems do shallow and/or single-branch clone operations before starting the steps in the .github.yml or .gitlab.yml or whatever file. Sometimes you have control over this and sometimes you don't. (OP mentioned GitLab, which I have not used; for GitHub the trick is to choose the right checkout action in the GitHub action configuration, or set the fetch depth to 0 for checkout@v2.)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. `git diff --name-status origin/master HEAD` works for me. But the other two commands still meet the error "unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

Comment: ok : check the values of said variables when your script is run (for example : `echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`), you can also check what variables are defined : `env | sort` or `env | grep "^CI" | sort`